# 15 meters vs. 15-meter

Tags: adjectives

> 1.The height of Merlion is 15 meters.
>
> 2.The height of Merlion is 15-meter.

Which one is correct? Can we use this hyphenated adjective as predicative adjective?

Comment: You need a unit, right? So, the first one is my choice. 15-meter is a compound noun which can be used as an adjective.

Comment: Thanks a lot.Acoording to your advice, I've known that 15- meter can be used as an adjective.

Comment: Note that the spelling is meters in the US and metres in the UK.

Answer (score 2):

Expressions like *N-meter-high*, *N-meter-long*, *N-year-old* etc. where *N* stands for a number can ONLY be used in attributive position. Notice that I'm placing extra emphasis on the word "only". An attributive position is when an adjective or a phrase functioning as an adjective is placed before the noun it modifies:

> Merlion is a **15-meter-high** building.
>
> It's a **10-foot-long** ladder.
>
> He is a **46-year-old** man.

If you want to say the same thing in postpositive position (an adjective or a phrase functioning as an adjective is said to be in an postpositive position when it comes after the noun it modifies), then there should be no hyphenation going on and measure words like *meter*, *foot*, *year* etc. should be pluralized:

> Merlion is **15 meters high**.
>
> The ladder is **10 feet long**.
>
> He is **46 years old**.

Comment: This explains when you need to hyphenate compond adjectives. https://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/hyphens.asp